# Ограничение типов в Котлин для Array<T>

Tags: kotlin, generics, типы

У меня есть следующий код:

```
    private fun <T> checkSize(srcData: List<List<T>>) {
        require(srcData.isNotEmpty())
        srcData.forEach {
            require(srcData.size == it.size)
        }
    }
```

Я хотел бы, чтобы он работал и для `srcData: Array<Array<T>>`, но дело в том, что Array не имплементирует никакой интерфейс, поэтому я не могу сделать, например:

```
fun <T : Collection<Collection<Any>>> checkSize(srcData: T) {...}
```

Единственный выход - дублирование кода для массивов, что мне не очень нравится. Есть ли ещё варианты?

P.S.
Пытался сделать так, но почему то умное приведение Котлина не работает в этом случае:

```
    private fun <T> checkSize(srcData: T) {
        if (srcData is Array<*> || srcData is Collection<*>) {
            require(srcData.isNotEmpty()) { ERR_SIZE_EM }
            srcData.forEach {
                if (it is Array<*> || it is Collection<*>)
                    require(srcData.size == it.size) { ERR_SIZE_SQ }
            }
        }
    }
```

Однако, если убрать `||` (оставив какое то одно условие), то всё будет работать.

Comment: Массив это базовый тип языка, а список и коллекции -- нет. Либо дублируете, либо на лету преобразуете `array.toList()`.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, тогда можете, пожалуйста, ответить на дополненный вопрос?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja тогда уж asList

Comment: @oQaris, опять же, у базового типа и интерфейса из стандартной библиотеки нет ничего общего, поэтому никакое умное приведение вам не поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно пытаться совместить несовместимое. Что вам мешает сделать вот так?

```
private fun <T> checkSize(srcData: Array<Array<T>>) {
    checkSize(srcData.asList().map { it.asList() })
}

private fun <T> checkSize(srcData: List<List<T>>) {
    require(srcData.isNotEmpty())
    srcData.forEach {
        require(srcData.size == it.size)
    }
}
```